# Converting a C++/Python desktop application to web app

Tags: c#, python, c++, .net, django

I have a desktop application that's essentially a glorified Monte Carlo simulation. The simulation is written in C++ (<10,000 lines of code) and the GUI, which calls the .exe is written in python (don't ask, I had (bad) reasons). I'm looking to convert this to a web application on Azure, which I know is going to be a less than trivial task, but I'm hoping to get advice on how to best do this. From how I see this, I have three options, modifying the C++ code and somehow converting this to a web app, rewriting entirely in the .NET framework using C#, or rewriting entirely with Django/Python. Regardless of what I do, I'll have a ton to learn, and I'll need to completely rewrite the front end.

Modifying the C++ code seemed like the best option at first. However, after doing some research, I'm thinking my modifications will be heavy, and C++ really isn't an ideal fit for web apps to begin with. I'm worried that between the likely heavy modifications and the finagling I'll have to do with C++, that will greatly outweigh me getting to reuse a good amount of code.

The next option would be to to completely rewrite the program using .NET and C#. I don't know C#, but I've read where it's not a tough transition to learn C# after knowing C++. I also feel like "translating" certain chunks of C++ code will be manageable, as the languages are so similar.

The final option I see is Python and Django. Obviously, knowing Python should help, but I feel like I'll have to do even more rewriting, as it's less similar to C++. I'm also worried about performance, as I'm assuming python will be slower to complete the simulation than C#.

Obviously this is going to be a pretty large undertaking for myself regardless of the option I choose, but minimizing the difficulty is certainly a top priority here. In addition, performance is a huge consideration, as the user is under a time crunch, and the more iterations the simulation can run, the better the result.

For longer term considerations, I would like this to be something that can be worked on in the future. Additionally, I do hope to continue writing web apps after I complete this first project. These two considerations make me even more focused on doing this "right" and not just quick.

Comment: Any answer can only be based on opinion, which isn't a great fit for Stack Overflow. The way I see it, you will have to rewrite it. Which platform you do it on is something only you can answer. C# might be close to C++ in syntax, but it's really a whole different thing. (think of spoken languages that have the same grammar, but different vocabulary)

Comment: Thanks, that is true in regards to this being an opinion question, but I do appreciate yours. I guess my main concern with using python is the performance. Would it be likely be significantly slower than C#? If so, that answers my question on which path to take. If that's not necessarily true, I'll have to do more research on which one would be best for me.

Comment: I don't think you can universally say that one would be faster than the other. You can [look for general comparisons](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+vs+django+performance), but any difference in performance is unlikely to be discernible unless your application is under high load, and even then, it depends on how you write it.

Comment: I mean, rewriting a program from scratch isn't necessarily easy either--depending on how big it is, of course.

Comment: 10k lines is not much but rewriting a software could introduce news bugs.